# How to Apply a .reg file to a ntuser.man file

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, roaming-profile

I have a .reg file with some registry updates that I need to apply to a bunch of user's profiles.   The keys are all in HKCU, which means they will end up in ntuser.man.

The "manual" way of doing this is to log in as each user, run the .reg file, and then copy the resulting man file back up to the roaming profile on the network.

Common sense tells me there must be a better way to do this.  somehow there must be a way to merge that .reg file into a man file without actually being logged into a computer as the user being affected.  I am not a windows admin, or at least not supposed to be, so forgive me if this is an utterly stupid question :)

Answer (score 1):

You mention that these are roaming profiles which makes me assume you're running AD.  If so, why not just use Group Policy Preferences to push the registry values?  Manually editing hive files seems so archaic.

Comment: it does sound archaic to me, even as a software engineer with little windows admin experience.  I am clearly out of my comfort zone here, but my general common sense told me our current method was crazy.  I will see if i can convince our AD folks here to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Load hive" functionality of REGEDIT.EXE for loading ntuser.man file for editing (select HKEY_USERS branch to activate "Load hive" menu item).

But seems you can't import your REG file directly in this case because there is no HKEY_CURRENT_USER and you should select correct registry branch for user settings using user SID.